# getElementsByClass and appendChild - how to modify only the last element of the class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use .appendChild on the last element of an HTML collection of all elements with the same class. 
I'm looking for a way to add a button only to the last element of this collection. 
To find the index of this element, I tried to get the length of the collection and store it into a variable.

```
numberofalerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert").length
```

and then to refer the value of this variable with the bracket notation on getElementsByClassName[].appendChild.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[numberofalerts].appendChild(closebutton)
```

However, it returns undefined.

I suspect this is because i'm using wrongly the bracket notation...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numberofalerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert").length
```

This will give you length of the array but the array index always starts from 0 to `length-1`. When you write `document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[numberofalerts].appendChild(closebutton)`, it will give you undefined coz the last index will be on less than length. Change it to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[numberofalerts-1].appendChild(closebutton)
```

```js
var numberofalerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert").length;

var closebutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLOSE");       // Create a text node
closebutton.appendChild(t);    
document.getElementsByClassName("alert")[numberofalerts-1].appendChild(closebutton)
```

```html
<div class="alert">1</div>
<div class="alert">2</div>
<div class="alert">3</div>
<div class="alert">4</div>
```